# Xcode 6 Beta5: Why 'UITableViewCell' is not a subtype of 'NSNumber'?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I tried to implement the function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in my `ViewController` that implements the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    ...

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell;
        if !cell {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = "row \(indexPath.row)";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = "row details \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell;
    }
```

It is a faithful translation from the objective-c code counterpart (I suppose).

However, swift compiler flags this error message: "'UITableViewCell' is not a subtype of 'NSNumber'"

[image]

If I changed the implementation to

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell;

    cell.textLabel.text = "row \(indexPath.row)";
    // cell.detailTextLabel.text = "row details \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell;
}
```

The compiler error is gone and the App seems to work as I expect.

My question:

1) Why swift compiler emitted this error message?

2) What is the proper syntax to test variable `cell` is null or not? Apparently swift is expected a NSNumber here. Is it because of the `!` operator?

3) Does it make sense to check if `cell` is null? I suppose when I used `as UITableViewCell` in the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call, I have already excluded the possibility of nil. Does swift thereby guarantee the function `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to always return a UITableViewCell? It is different from objective-c behaviour.

Comment: I'd guess that you're getting the comelier message that you're getting because the `!` operator only acts on Boolean subtypes of NSNumber (or Bool in swift). So the compiler is expecting a subtype of NSNumber because you've used the `!` operator where it is no longer allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explictly test for nil. See the release notes for XCode 6 Beta 5.

```
if cell != nil {
    ...
}
```

The compiler message is misleading, though.

> Optionals no longer conform to the BooleanType (formerly LogicValue) protocol, so they
>   may no longer be used in place of boolean expressions (they must be explicitly compared with
>   v != nil).

Comment: That raises `'UITableViewCell' is not a subtype of 'NSString'` on that line.